# Uninstall a program from linux bug

Tags: linux

i'm new to linux and i need to remove apache-fop from ubuntu :

So here what i did :

```
dpkg --list | grep fop
ii  fop                                    1:1.0.dfsg2-6                              XML formatter driven by XSL Formatting Objects (XSL-FO.)
ii  libfop-java                            1:1.1.dfsg-2ubuntu1                        XML formatter driven by XSL Formatting Objects (XSL-FO.)
```

and to remove :

```
amira@amira:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get remove libfop-java_1.1.dfsg-2ubuntu1_all.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libfop-java_1.1.dfsg-2ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libfop-java_1.1.dfsg-2ubuntu1_all.deb'
```

So what's wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to give the .deb or version numbers. Just try

```
sudo apt-get remove libfop-java
```

Comment: Downvote? Why? That's exactly his problem.

Comment: the old installed fop was broken this is why i i uninstalled it . Now i need to install the latest version 1.1 , so i download the binary distribution and do this sudo apt-get install fop-1.1-bin.tar.gz but i get this Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fop-1.1-bin.tar.gz
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'fop-1.1-bin.tar.gz'
What do you think please.

Comment: You have the same problem. The packages is simply called "fop".

Comment: You can search for packages in a few different ways, one is "aptitude search <package_name>".